# Netty trims data while sending

Tags: java, tcp, apache-camel, netty

I have a `esb` running on `came`l, after writing my return string to the buffer my `client listener` only reads some of the `data`. I debugged a lot but cannot find a proper solution.

```
public class EsiIncomingStringEncoder extends org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.string.StringEncoder{
IChannelFactory esiChannelDatasource;

public IChannelFactory getEsiChannelDatasource() {
    return esiChannelDatasource;
}

public void setEsiChannelDatasource(IChannelFactory esiChannelDatasource) {
    this.esiChannelDatasource = esiChannelDatasource;
}

private String convertToString(Object obj, Charset cp) {
    if(obj == null)
        return "";
    if(obj instanceof String)
        return (String) obj;
    if(obj instanceof byte[])
        return new String((byte[])obj, cp);
    if(obj instanceof ByteBuffer)
        return new String(cp.decode((ByteBuffer)obj).array());
    return obj.toString();
}

protected Object encode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Channel channel, Object msg) throws Exception {
    IChannel esiChannel = lookupChannel(channel);
    String data = convertToString(msg, esiChannel.getCharset());
    //int dataLength = data.length();

    logData(channel, dataToSend);
    return ChannelBuffers.copiedBuffer(dataToSend, esiChannel.getCharset());
}...
```

When I debug, I can see that `"dataToSend"` string is written to buffer correctly, which is a `123400 byte array` , In my receiving thread , I can only read `13123` byte no more, since I put the length of my message in the first part, my thread waits to read the rest of the stream.

I don't if there is a problem in`netty` to send such big byte array on Linux.

PS: If I test with shorter string there is no problem to receiving data.

PPS: camel version 2.9.0

Comment: See answers to related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29067539/netty-weird-indexoutofboundsexception-readerindex-length-exceeds-writerindex

Comment: OK I added  a code line in encode method like this channel.getConfig().setOption("sendBufferSize", dataLenghth); the problem seems solved , but this is silly to set this data in every message!